# Populate class from query on VB Net

Tags: vb.net

Help translate C# code from this link [Simplest way to populate class from query in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693583/simplest-way-to-populate-class-from-query-in-c-sharp/32694421#32694421) to VB Net.

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.Reflection

Private Sub Main()
    Dim connectionString = "..."
    Dim records = (New Query(connectionString)).SqlQuery(Of TVChannel)("select top 10 * from TVChannel")
End Sub

Private Class TVChannel
    Public Property number() As String
    Public Property title() As String
    Public Property favoriteChannel() As String
    Public Property description() As String
    Public Property packageid() As String
    Public Property format() As String
End Class

Public Class Query
    Private ReadOnly _connectionString As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal connectionString As String)
        _connectionString = connectionString
    End Sub

    Public Function SqlQuery(Of T)(ByVal query As String) As List(Of T)
        Dim result = New List(Of T)()

        Using connection = New SqlConnection(_connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Using command = connection.CreateCommand()
                command.CommandText = query
                Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                    Dim columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(Function(f) reader.GetName(f)).ToArray()
                    Dim properties = GetType(T).GetProperties()

                    Do While reader.Read()
                        Dim data = New Object(reader.FieldCount - 1){}
                        reader.GetValues(data)

                        Dim instance = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T)), T)

                        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
                            If data(i) Is DBNull.Value Then
                                data(i) = Nothing
                            End If

                            Dim [property] = properties.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name.Equals(columns(i), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))

                            If [property] IsNot Nothing Then
                                [property].SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(data(i), [property].PropertyType))
                            End If
                        Next i
                        result.Add(instance)
                    Loop
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

but, I got error on this line

```
Dim instance = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(T)), T)
```

System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

Comment: fyi, this code will force you to write follow really insecure practices. To understand why, read up on sql injection attacks. There's no way in this code to pass parameter data separate from the sql command string.

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked without issue for me.  I added a constructor with a parameter to that `TVChannel` class and then I got the same exception.  I think that you're lying to us.

Comment: Also, the problem here isn't anything to do with the C# to VB translation. The original code would have failed in this situation, too. The problem is the `TVChannel` type is **private**.

Comment: Finally, there's a **HUGE** difference between `data[i] = null` in the original and `data(i) = Nothing` in this code. For example, the VB code will assign a `0` value to numeric properties rather than `null`, where the C# would do something different.

Comment: As a note, you can have just: `Private Function GetInstanceOfT(Of T As New)() As T Dim t1 = New T  (...) Return t1 End Function`. So you can call: `Dim newTv = GetInstanceOfT(Of TVChannel)()`

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, you right, I go error cause I use 'String' as object. thank's….

Answer (score 0):

This is a much better pattern to follow. It addresses at least four issues in the original code (sql injection, Nothing vs null, constructor access, unnecessary allocations):

```
Public Module SQL
    Private ReadOnly _connectionString As String = "..."

    Public Iterator Function Query(Of T)(ByVal query As String, translate As Func(IDataRecord, T), ParamArray data() As SqlParameter) As IEnumerable(Of T)    
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(_connectionString), _
              command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)

            If data IsNot Nothing Then command.Parameters.AddRange(data)
            connection.Open()

            Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read()
                    Yield translate(reader)
                End While
                reader.Close()
            End Using
        End Using                       
    End Function
End Module
```

Call it like this:

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim records = SQL.Query("select top 10 * from TVChannel", 
        Function(r) 
             'Yes, you're doing the mapping manually now for each query.
             'But this lets you properly account for things NULL, column name mismatches, computed properties, etc.
             Return New TVChannel With {
                     .number = r["number"],
                     .title = r["title"],
                     .favoriteChannel = r["favoriteChannel"],
                     .description = r["description"],
                     .packageid = r["packageid"],
                     .format = r["format"]
             }
        End Function,
        Nothing)

    For Each channel As TVChannel In records
        Console.WriteLine($"Channel {channel.number}, {channel.title}")
    Next
End Sub
```